# Enable Lexical Binding by Binding “lexical-binding” to t

Tags: quote, let-binding, customization, eval, backquote

(Please see what is [`letrec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#index-letrec) first.)

The following code is obviously fine and self-explanatory:

```lisp
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(setq post-self-insert-hook `(,@(when (boundp 'post-self-insert-hook)
                                  post-self-insert-hook)
                              ,(letrec ((_ (lambda ()
                                             (message ":P")
                                             (remove-hook 'post-self-insert-hook _))))
                                 _)))
```

But if I use `custom-set-variables`,

```lisp
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(custom-set-variables
 '(post-self-insert-hook `(,@(when (boundp 'post-self-insert-hook)
                               post-self-insert-hook)
                           ;; Manual says `letrec' is
                           ;; only useful when lexical
                           ;; binding is in effect.
                           ;; But `custom-set-variables'
                           ;; evaluates these forms by
                           ;; calling `eval', which uses
                           ;; dynamic scope by default.
                           ,(let ((lexical-binding t))
                              (letrec ...)))))
```

Emacs will complain that `Symbol’s value as variable is void: _`.

Why the above code snippet doesn't work?

---

###### Irrelevant to This Question

For those who are not quite familiar with *backquote*:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(post-self-insert-hook `(,@(when (boundp 'post-self-insert-hook)
                               post-self-insert-hook)
                           ,(let ((_ (lambda () "123")))
                              _))))
;; => nil

post-self-insert-hook
;; => (... (lambda nil "123"))
```

As you can see, the forms that are expected to be evaluated are indeed evaluated.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Seems like you started with a question, but you answered it in the question. Maybe you want to post that part as an answer instead, explaining a bit about it to help readers understand easier?

Comment: @Drew: Alright, instead of explaining more, it might be more straightforward to just delete the sentence following 'why'. I will do that

Comment: It is not really surprising, is it? In the first `custom-set-variables`, the expression is quoted, so nothing inside it gets evaluated. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NickD: Perhaps you missed something. `custom-set-variables` uses `eval` to evaluate `[backquote](,@(...) ,(letrec ...))` and then set the result as the value of `post-self-insert-hook`.

Comment: @Drew: I think this question is about `elisp` now. Can I add this tag? :P

Comment: Not in my opinion. When there are more-specific tags that cover it, don't use `elisp`. E.g., tag `elisp-macros` for Qs about Elisp macros. (I added tag `eval` here.) Tag `elisp` (IMO) is essentially for Qs about differences between Elisp and other Lisps.

Comment: Another tag that might be useful here is `lexical-binding`. Pick the (max 5) tags you think are most appropriate/helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Op missed the expected behavior of the code snippet, and does not provide the full code to reproduce the issue, which seriously obscurified the problem.

Short answer is, `custom-set-variables` used `eval` without setting the optional argument that enabled lexical scoping, so the arguments
of `custom-set-variables` is eval in dynamic scope, thus `letrec` would not produce a closure as expected.

**Switching between lexical/dynamic scoping should be done before *parsing* the program and cannot be changed by binding `lexical-binding` inside the program.**

For example, in a new buffer using *dynamic scope* by default,

```lisp
(let ((lexical-binding t))
  (lambda ()))
;; => (lambda nil)
```

then if you enable *lexical binding* and evaluate

```lisp
(let ((lexical-binding nil))
  (lambda ()))
;; => (closure (t) nil)
```

It's obvious that `(let ((lexical-binding nil/t)) ...)` doesn't take effect.

---

Besides, just don't assume one who knows `letrec` can read your intension.  As a punishment to Op, try explain how yin-yang puzzle works.